# How to accommodate for the iPhone 4 screen resolution?

Tags: iphone, screen-resolution

According to [Apple](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html), the iPhone 4 has a new and better screen resolution:

> 3.5-inch (diagonal) widescreen Multi-Touch display
>   960-by-640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi

This little detail affects our apps in a heavy way. Most of the demo apps on the net have one thing in common: They position views in the believe that the screen has a fixed size of 320 x 480 pixels. So what most (if not all) developers do is: they designed everything in such a way, that a touchable area is (for example) 50 x 50 pixels big. Just enough to tap it. Things have been positioned relative to the upper left, to reach a specific position on screen - let's say the center, or somewhere at the bottom.

When we develop high-resolution apps, they probably won't work on older devices. And if they do, they would suffer a lot from 4-times the size of any image, having to scale them down in memory.

Comment: Although I disagree with closing based on being subjective, there isn't a way to really answer this until the new phones are released and people can play with them.

Comment: That's silly - the consequence of this is pretty logical. You can simulate that easily by transforming your main view to half size and hight while giving it double the size and hight. I did, and it sucks.

Comment: Why does all good questions end up as community wiki's?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [*Supporting High-Resolution Screens In Views*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html), from the Apple docs:

> On devices with high-resolution screens, the `imageNamed:`,
>   `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, and
>   `initWithContentsOfFile:` methods
>   automatically looks for a version of
>   the requested image with the `@2x`
>   modifier in its name. It if finds one,
>   it loads that image instead. If you do
>   not provide a high-resolution version
>   of a given image, the image object
>   still loads a standard-resolution
>   image (if one exists) and scales it
>   during drawing.
>
> When it loads an image, a UIImage object automatically sets the size and
>   scale properties to appropriate values
>   based on the suffix of the image file.
>   For standard resolution images, it
>   sets the scale property to 1.0 and
>   sets the size of the image to the
>   image’s pixel dimensions. For images
>   with the @2x suffix in the filename,
>   it sets the scale property to 2.0 and
>   halves the width and height values to
>   compensate for the scale factor. These
>   halved values correlate correctly to
>   the point-based dimensions you need to
>   use in the logical coordinate space to
>   render the image.

Comment: Mind you that UIKit views are drawn at the right scale no matter the resolution, de facto.
Custom images being of concern, as addressed above. (Which is why you shouldn't use them to draw your interface when you can.)

Comment: @mystify, my understanding `@2x` is part of the name. Quote from the same pdf, "For example, if you have two image files, named `Button.png` and `Button@2x.png`, you would use the following code to request your button image:
`UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button"];`"

Comment: What about iOS3.0? What can you do there to display high-resolution images on iPhone 4? I sure want my apps to look great, but I also want people with 3.x to be able to use it...

Answer (score 6):

This is purely speculation, but if the resolution really is 960 x 640 - that's exactly twice as high a resolution as the current version. It would be trivially simple for the iPhone to check the apps build target and detect a legacy version of the app and simply scale it by 2. You'd never notice the difference.

Answer (score 5):

[Engadget's reporting of the keynote](http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/07/steve-jobs-live-from-wwdc-2010/) included the following transcript from Steve Jobs

> ...It makes it so your apps run
>   automatically on this, but it renders
>   your text and controls in the higher
>   resolution. Your apps look even
>   better, but if you do a little bit of
>   work, then they will look stunning. So
>   we suggest that you do that

So I infer from that, if you use existing APIs your app will get scaled up. If you take advantage of new iOS4 APIs, you can get all groovy with the new pixels.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the display will be ok but I'm concerned about the logic in my game. Will touchesBegan positions return points in the new resolution? The screen bounds will be different, these types of things could potentially be problems for me.

Comment: No. That stuff is done with CoreGraphics (I think), which is resolution independent.

Comment: Without risking ANY NDA issues, all iPhones have always returned points, not pixels.  Since points are used in SDK 3.2 for iPad, I would not expect this to change for iPhone versions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Scaling to a double resolution for display purpose is straight forward, but will this scalling apply to all api's that input/output a screen coordinate? If not things are going to break aren't they?

Fair enough if it's been handled extensively throughout the framework.. I would imagine there are a lot of potential api's this effects.

Comment: I guess that the point where the calculations are done is so much low level, that any API is on top of that. So they could easily read a value from info.plist to see if the app is high resolution or not, and then handle any user interaction with the touchscreen or any drawing operation the appropriate way. Well, at least that's what I would have done when I was the chief of the iPhone SDK team ;-) ...According to Jobs that's not gonna break our apps. iPhone 4 buyers would hate it a lot if suddenly like 95% of all apps don't work on their new, super expensive device.

Comment: That's good if the forward thinking was in the design. I wouldn't be surprised though if this was overlooked. I suppose I'm hoping to find some confirmation of whether this is true from someone with the sdk that can test it.

Comment: I fear most of us, outside the US, will have to wait a long time until we're able to see it. Unless the new iPhone Simulator will be able to show up that new resultion.

Comment: The iPhone simulator has 3 target devices: iPad, iPhone and iPhone 4. iPhone 4 shows the high resolution (i.e. I have to scroll to see the whole screen on my 15'' Macbook pro)

Answer (score 3):

For people who are coming to this thread looking for a solution to a mobile web interface, check out this post on the Webkit blog: http://webkit.org/blog/55/high-dpi-web-sites/

It seems that Webkit has solved this problem four years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is true.

According to WWDC it appears that apple has build it some form of automatic conversion so that the resolution for applications will not be completely off. Think up-convert for dvd to HDTV's.

My guess would be that apple knows what most of the standards developers have been using and will already be using these for an immediate conversion. Of course if you are programming an application to take advantage of the new resolution it will look much nicer than whatever the result of apples auto-conversion is.

Comment: but keeping in mind that providing all graphics with 4 times the size (which is when you double hight and width), all old devices will suffer hard, loading giant files and scaling them down.

Comment: perhaps, we do not know if apple will make distinctions between iphone 4 apps and legacy iphone apps the same way that they do between iphone and ipad apps. Its possible if something is designed explicitly for the iphone 4 that they will not be available for the previous versions.

Comment: that would make sense. The previous versions can't deal with that, and it would be stupid to hurt those weak, age old devices with high res graphics which they have to scale down.

Comment: It is still a downer if you need to bundle your binary with all the extra graphics. 1 MB of png's would become 5 MB of png's.

Answer (score 2):

All of your labels and system buttons will be at 326dpi but your images will still be pixel doubled until you add the hi-res resources. I am currently updating my apps. If you build and run on the iPhone 4 sim then it is presented at 50%, go to Window > Scale > 100% to see the real difference! Labels are smooth, my images look shocking!