# iPhone4 960x640 - impact to apps?

Tags: iphone, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to accommodate for the different screen resolution of iPhone 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992360/how-to-accommodate-for-the-different-screen-resolution-of-iphone-4)

What does the new resolution mean for existing applications?

Do the devtools make it easy to support new resolutions without changes, if so how? what happens to apps by those developers who dont do things properly to leverage this?

What are the rules for resolution compliance for app acceptance on the app store?

Comment: Thanks, yes this does appear to be a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new OS should (As Steve Jobs stated during the keynote) detect whether or not the app is built for the new res and scale accordingly.  The new resolution is just double the old, so it should be a simple scale-up on the operating system's end.

All of the current UI elements will support the new resolution once iOS4 is released, so all a developer will have to do is update their custom images.

Comment: Ok, that's straight forward for the apps on iphone4.

Though I didnt write it, I was also interested how these questions would come into play for iphone apps running on the ipad (assuming they can) which I assume has a different resolution again.

Comment: Similar situation.  The iPad supports iPhone applications natively and scales them to work with its resolution.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you update all your custom graphics to use the new resolution, but then somebody installs the app on any of the older phone models or on an iPod Touch.

Comment: Oh, so iphone apps on ipad just appear really large? Kind of yuck, but I guess it should at least avoid "most" rounding issues for scaling to a non integral multiple size.

Answer (score 6):

According to page 75 of the latest (2010-06-04) iPhone App Programming Guide.pdf:

> On devices with high-resolution
>   screens, the `imageNamed:`,
>   `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, and
>   `initWithContentsOfFile:` methods
>   automatically looks for a version of
>   the requested image with the @2x
>   modifier in its name. It if finds one,
>   it loads that image instead. If you do
>   not provide a high-resolution version
>   of a given image, the image object
>   still loads a standard-resolution
>   image (if one exists) and scales it
>   during drawing.
>
> When it loads an
>   image, a UIImage object automatically
>   sets the size and scale properties to
>   appropriate values based on the suffix
>   of the image file. For standard
>   resolution images, it sets the scale
>   property to 1.0 and sets the size of
>   the image to the image’s pixel
>   dimensions. For images with the @2x
>   suffix in the filename, it sets the
>   scale property to 2.0 and halves the
>   width and height values to compensate
>   for the scale factor. These halved
>   values correlate correctly to the
>   point-based dimensions you need to use
>   in the logical coordinate space to
>   render the image.

Comment: What about 3.0? That does not have a method for, either getting screen resolution or correctly displaying "@2x"-images..

Comment: ＠Emil, you can safely assume there is no hi-res in 3.0. iPad is 3.2. Future devices are all 4.0 or newer.