# What does the new " Retina Display" mean for iPhone Developers?

Tags: iphone, backwards-compatibility

Apple announced a higher res display for the iPhone 4, yesterday. What does this mean for developers? More detection code and image swapping?

Can and should I just develop for iPhone 4 and let iphone 3 and down scale everything?

EDIT:

Perhaps the other way is better?

Comment: I believe this information is currently under NDA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to accommodate for the different screen resolution of iPhone 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992360/how-to-accommodate-for-the-different-screen-resolution-of-iphone-4)

Comment: @Colin Gislason - This question does not discuss anything that has not been publicly announced by apple. i just wanted to know opinions on scaling up or down from the developers perspective and what people suggest regarding legacy code. If there is something under NDA, please mention specifics.

Comment: What I meant was, the factual answer is under NDA. e.g. what APIs are available. General discussion is obviously ok. Look for the answers in the "iPhone Application Programming Guide" for the new GM.

Comment: @Colin - agreed. By the way, is the GM permitted for use to submit apps to Apple?

Comment: @Moshe From what I can tell, it is. Seems we can start submitting for iOS 4 tomorrow (June 10) and I doubt they will be releasing another version before then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or initially the opposite? That it just pixeldoubles legacy code? Downscaling will probably look bad.

Comment: downscaling a factor 2 always looks better than up sampling a factor 2. In the latter case you have to add non-existent information while in the former you already have all info and have to intelligently combine the excess info

Comment: If you happen to have any text in the bitmap, downscaling it could make it less readable.  For example, a lowercase "m" could be downscaled into a lowercase "n" by removing critical pixels.

Comment: @Toad - I agree with Kevin here. Bitmap text will get ruined, probably. Otherwise, you are right, downscaling usually is better.