# Will the next iPhone Simulator be able to simulate the high resolution of iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992360/how-to-accommodate-for-the-iphone-4-screen-resolution), the next one is: Will we be able to simulate our interfaces how they look on the new high resolution display, even without owning an iPhone 4?

I guess that there is a formula that we can use to calculate the exact needed distance between our monitors and our eyes, to achieve the exact same visual effect of the Retina Display. This would help a lot to get things right. The first thing we need is an high resolution iPhone Simulator. I can't get any sleep until I know.

Comment: All will be revealed once the iPhone OS/SDK 4 is publicly released.

Comment: Maybe - but I guess the lucky folks at WWDC already know that and can answer. They're all there with iPads and 3G, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the next iPhone Simulator be able to simulate the high resolution of iPhone 4?

Yes.

> I guess that there is a formula that we can use to calculate the exact needed distance between our monitors and our eyes, to achieve the exact same visual effect of the Retina Display.

Er, just multiple all coordinates by 2. The dimensions of iPhone 4 are same as before, just the resolution is doubled.

Comment: haha ... no that's not so simple. Your monitor (not the one of your phone) has a different pixel size, so this DPI must go into the formula, together with the DPI of the new iPhone 4 and it's exact screen size. That would allow to calculate the exact distance you need to have between your eyes and your mac monitor (whatever device that is - an samsung syncmaster or cinema display, they're all different)

Answer (score 2):

The current iOS 4 simulator already comes with a `iPhone 4` hardware option. It works like the iPad simulator, i.e. option to view at 100% or 50% zoom.