# Will artwork created for iPhone 3G need to be updated for iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, resolution

I've created artwork for apps on the iPhone 3G.  I want to make these apps available on the iPhone 4.  Does the new screen resolution on the iPhone 4 require re-sizing all the artwork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it required, no. Apple has said iOS4 will scale graphics for existing apps as necessary for the iPhone 4, so all existing apps will be compatible with iOS4 and the iPhone4 (assuming your app doesn't make use of private API's)

However, if you wish, you are free to issue an update to your app with higher resolution images.

[This stack overflow question has more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992360/how-to-accommodate-for-the-iphone-4-screen-resolution)