# Update applications for iPhone 4 Retina Display

Tags: iphone, interface, user-interface, ios

I was just wondering how you would go about giving a application the new sharper images for the iPhone 4? i know the SDK already cleans up text and UI elements but how should I go about updating my image UI. Is there a different way (like a folder or file extension) to add the new images for the iPhone 4 or should I just go and add 960x640 size images and let the older iPhones scale it down?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to accommodate for the iPhone 4 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992360/how-to-accommodate-for-the-iphone-4-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very good and complete document from Apple covering just that. Check out the iPhone Application Programming Guide, it has a chapter on that very topic.

Edit: The [link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html)

Comment: Thanks,should have checked there first.