# iphone how to convert my app to retina display app

Tags: iphone, retina-display

How can I convert my current application to retina display app and I've to make sure that the same app works in iphone 3 as well.
If its just to update my images to high resolution, it will also work in iphone 3. then there will be no meaning for "retina display" app.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.jannisnikoy.nl/index.php/2010/08/optimizing-apps-for-apples-retina-display) out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update applications for iPhone 4 Retina Display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128811/update-applications-for-iphone-4-retina-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retina Display version will use a higher resolution of an image (if it's supplied in the app). Refer to the Apple [doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html) for details.