# How to port an app from old iPhone to iPhone 4? (Retina Display)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

Sorry if im asking something stupid but please dont shoot me down!

I have done a little playing in xcode but nothing more than a button press counter kindof thing..

I was curious.. when developing with the retina display in mind you obviously produce higher resolutions png's and what not for the new display..

How would you go about making the app run on a lower resolution iPhone?

Would you use the same high res graphics and have the OS do the rest of the work or do you need to write in a chunk of code to switch the graphics based on the device?

Again sorry if its in the documentation but i couldnt find it!

Thanks in advance..

- Daniel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update applications for iPhone 4 Retina Display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128811/update-applications-for-iphone-4-retina-display)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to read the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Especially [Supporting High-Resolution Screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html).