# Will the "Retina Display" affect developers?

Tags: iphone, retina-display

As an iPhone app developer, should I take some steps (especially for graphics) to make them look correctly on iPhone 4 "Retina Display" or is there no such an issue?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to accommodate for the iPhone 4 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992360/how-to-accommodate-for-the-iphone-4-screen-resolution)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retina Display (iPhone, iPad) HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778091/retina-display-iphone-ipad-html/9778164#9778164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using vector graphics you're going to want to make provide high res versions of all your images, otherwise it will look pants on the new display.

Other than that I don't think you'll need to do much else.

Answer (score 3):

The following page, from the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), might be an interesting read : [**Supporting High-Resolution Screens**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html)

Comment: The link above is "outdated", says Apple. It takes you to the main page :(

Answer (score 1):

Use vector graphics so everything scales beautifully on every device.

Comment: What type of file extensions are you speaking of? Would a .svg file be okay to use? I have never heard of using anything but a .png file. I use Inskcape to make my .png images from .svg files.

Comment: Whatever's supported. I hope SVG is!

Comment: I don't write iOS apps, I currently write web apps. sorry.