# Retina Display (iPhone, iPad) HTML

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, retina-display

How can I improve my HTML site by having Retina Graphics for iPhone and iPad users?  How would I get started?

Comment: I guess you're getting downvoted because a simple search would yield some good answers to your question. Though this pure speculation since nobody is leaving a comment.

Comment: This might be useful http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/12/adding-retina-graphics-to-your-website/ or this https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&pq=retina%20graphics%20website&cp=25&gs_id=n&xhr=t&q=retina+graphics+webdesign&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=retina+graphics+webdesign&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ed3a1cc0755514de&biw=1919&bih=1101&ix=seb&ion=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good [resource](http://de-online.co.uk/2012/03/18/retina-ipad-vs-the-web) to get started with adapting your html site to retina display
actually that doesn't involve having retina graphics but changing the way html is presented to look more adapted